# Running python script on web browser

Tags: python, csv, web, download

I am new to python. I have created a Script which asks the user to add date and file name and then generates csv file. I want to run that Script on our network. So that everyone on the network can put the dates and generate their report. Can anybody please suggest me which module should i use and how.Although my script is generating two files , i only want everyone to download Revenue report not the missing id's.

here is the snippet from my program which is calling all of my functions,i made.
Thanks in advance.

```
print "Enter state date(eg:-2015-01-01):",
start_date = raw_input()

print "Enter the last date(eg:-2015-01-01):",
end_date=raw_input()

print "Please give a filename for this report(eg:-January_rev_report): ",
file_name=raw_input()
in_file = open(""+file_name+".csv", "w")
in_file2=open("missiong_ids.csv","w")
in_file2.write("Missing_ids\n")
in_file.write("Partner_id|Partner_name|Price_of_lead|Date|Osdial_Lead_id|Bob_lead_id|list_id|Phone_number|State|Postal_code|Status\n")
data_=getPidsForThisMonth(start_date,end_date)
for j in data_:

    if getReport(j,start_date,end_date) is None:
        missing_ids=""
        missing_ids+=j
        #print missing_ids + " is missing id, the whole list of missing id's will be added to missing_ids.csv file "
        in_file2.write(missing_ids)

    else:   
        data=""
        details = getPartnerDetails(j)
        pid = str(details[0])
        name = str(details[1])
        price = str(details[2])
        report_data=getReport(j,start_date,end_date)
        date=str(report_data[0])
        lead_id=str(report_data[1])
        bob_id=str(report_data[2])
        list_id=str(report_data[3])
        phone=str(report_data[4])
        state=str(report_data[5])       
        postal_code=str(report_data[6])
        status=str(report_data[7])



        data+=pid+"|"+name+"|"+price+"|"+date +"|"+lead_id+"|"+bob_id+"|"+list_id+"|"+phone+"|"+state+"|"+postal_code+"|"+status
        data+="\n"
        in_file.write(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Flask would be suited to turn this into a small web-app: http://flask.pocoo.org/

I would have one controller that takes two parameters, the start- and end-date. Or better have a small page where dates can be selected and pass this using POST to a controller. This would run the script and return the file. If you set the response correctly the csv file will start as a download.

You won't need to write the file, just store the lines in a list and at the end generate the full content using '\n'.join(lines).